# facebook sdk once-only login webapp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I have a question for the facebook javascript sdk. Is it possible, and if yes how, that the user login only one time and then the user is always logged in instead of every application start go on the login button again? I try to make a webapp and run it with webview in android. Any apps have that function e.g. draw something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s what `FB.getLoginStatus` is for, it checks if the user authorized your App already and refreshes the Token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/